# What is the name of this art déco sans font?

Tags: font-identification

Can someone please tell me what font this this? [image: banner]

I have been looking for it on the internet and could not find the exact name of the font, it would be very good if someone could point out what the name of it is.

Thank you,
Gantig

Comment: Hi Gantig, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. We have a collection of font identification resources [right here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is a good idea to try those first. Please let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increase. Please don't be discouraged, we know that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you!

Answer (score 2):

Font is very similar to [Mostra Nuova Bold](http://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/mostra-nuova)

[link 2](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/marksimonson/mostra-nuova/)

[image]